# How to track clicks of one button and then another?

Tags: javascript

I need to track the click on capslock and then the keyboard shortcut ctrl + alt, that is, first click on capslock and then on the keyboard shortcut here is an example

```
if (e.code == "CapsLock") {
        if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 18) {
          alert();
        }
      }
```

but this code does not work

Answer (score 0):

I use a function like this:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    var caps = e.getModifierState && e.getModifierState('CapsLock');  // true if pressed, false if released
    document.onkeyup = function(event) {
    if(caps === true){
        /** Validate keys are to be processed */
        var keycode = event.which;
        // works off course only if ctrl key is kept pressed during key stroke = normal behavior in most OS
        // Should it work like a ctrl-Lock function you have to work with a state variable
            if ((event.ctrlKey === true) && (keycode === 18)) {  
                alert();
            }
            else{
                /** Let it happen, don't do anything */
                return;
            }
        }
    };
});
```